# WPF Binding in execution time

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have the following binding in my XAML file:

```
Fill="{Binding ElementName=cpRange1, Path=CurrentColor}"
```

What would be the syntax for setting this same building but in execution time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve. If you're trying to set binding on your object at runtime in the code behind, you should be able to do this:

For a given `Rectangle`

```
<Rectangle Name="MyRect"/>
```

In your code:

```
        // Property to bind (example)....
        public SolidColorBrush MyColor { get; set; }
        //

        // In some initialisation method.
        MyColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);

        Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyColor");
        MyRect.SetBinding(Rectangle.FillProperty, myBinding);
```

In your specific case, you would want to set `myBinding.ElementName`, and point `myBinding.Path` at a property on the element you wish to target.

I may have misunderstood your goal.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx)